# Google Volley Android: Login

Tags: php, android, android-volley, login-script

I'm trying to use Volley to send a Username and Password to a php which uses that inputs to compare then to see if everything is correct, and send back the informations, like name and picture, but I'm not understanding how to make this communication, on internet I've found how to receive, but not how to send values...
I'm beginner, so please be patient. xP
Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Basically you have to override the getParameter function of your Request to send datas to your server.

Comment: like this?
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("name", "text.name");
params.put("password", "text.pass");